# "Previous post" and "Next post" link in Show View (Nested Resources)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-resources

**In my Application I want to add a "Previous Article" and a "Next Article" link in the bottom of my Article Show View.**

This is what I have so far but I get this error:

```
undefined method `article_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd7c581af48>:0x007fd7cb8e5968>
```

I know the path must look like this (but i am having a hard time implementing it)

```
myapp/users/1/article/1
```

New to Rail Please Help ...

**ROUTES**

```
resources users do
  resources articles
end
```

**MODELS**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :photo

 has_many :articles

end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :user

  def next
    user.articles.where("id > ?", id).order("id ASC").first
  end

  def prev
    user.articles.where("id < ?", id).order("id DESC").first
  end

end
```

**VIEWS**

Articles Show Page appname/users/1/articles/1

```
<%= link_to @article.name %>

<%= link_to "next", @article.next %>
<%= link_to "previous", @article.prev %>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_publisher

  def get_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def show
    @article = @user.articles.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @articles = @user.articles
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
<%= link_to 'next', user_article_path(@user, @article.next) %>
```

And rest by analogy.

Comment: Glad to help. You can read about nested resources and routing here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: i needed to add if @article.next at the end. or else it would get a routing error. :)