# Undefined method with link to next comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471430/previous-post-and-next-post-link-in-show-view-nested-resources) as guidance I am trying to create a link to the next comment on my comments show page. I am getting this error however:

```
undefined method `next' for #<Comment:0x00000103d59db0>
```

In my routes comments belong to posts:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

In my posts model I have this:

```
 def next
   post.comments.where("id > ?", id).order("id ASC").first
end
```

My comments controller:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = Comment.find params[:id]
@commentnext = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
```

and then in my comments show view I have the link:

```
<%= link_to "Next Comment", post_comment_path(@post, @commentnext.next) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471430/previous-post-and-next-post-link-in-show-view-nested-resources)** you attached,I guess you put the `method` in **`wrong model`**.It should be in **`Comment`** model

Try putting this in the Comment model instead of Post model

```
#comment.rb
def next
   post.comments.where("id > ?", id).order("id ASC").first
end
```

Comment: Awesome, that was it. Any chance you'd know how to make the link the comment title instead of 'next'. I tried @commentnext.next.title with no success.

Comment: @user2759575 Try like this `<%= link_to "#{@comment.title}", post_comment_path(@post, @commentnext.next) %>`